# How can i convert this code to PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, layout, pyqt4, pyqt5

I have this code i want to convert this code from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Here is the code

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
 def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()
    self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):     
    hbox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
    left = QtGui.QFrame(self)       
    left.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    right = QtGui.QFrame(self)
    right.setFrameShape(QtGui.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    splitter = QtGui.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
    splitter.addWidget(left)
    splitter.addWidget(right)
    splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 1)
    splitter.setSizes([125, 150])
    hbox.addWidget(splitter)
    self.setLayout(hbox)
    QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle('QtGui.QSplitter')
    self.show()

def main():
  app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

How can i convert this code to pyqt5

[Here is image show the result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xofbt.png)

Comment: Change `from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore` to  `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,  QtGui, QtCore` and `QtGui.Q...` to `QtWidgets.Q...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
#from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5 import Qt

class Example(Qt.QWidget):
 def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

 def initUI(self):     
    hbox = Qt.QHBoxLayout(self)
    left = Qt.QFrame(self)       
    left.setFrameShape(Qt.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    left.setStyleSheet('background-color:lightblue; color: white; font-weight: bold;')
    labelLeft = Qt.QLabel(" \n left = Qt.QFrame(self)", left)

    right = Qt.QFrame(self)
    right.setFrameShape(Qt.QFrame.StyledPanel)
    labelRight = Qt.QLabel(" \n right = Qt.QFrame(self)", right)

    splitter = Qt.QSplitter(Qt.Qt.Horizontal)
    splitter.addWidget(left)
    splitter.addWidget(right)
    splitter.setStretchFactor(1, 1)
    splitter.setSizes([125, 150])
    hbox.addWidget(splitter)
    self.setLayout(hbox)

    Qt.QApplication.setStyle(Qt.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
    self.setWindowTitle('Qt.QSplitter')
    self.show()

def main():
  app = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

[image]